# Who brings up lvm volumes and how when booting?

Tags: systemd, lvm, device-mapper

I know the logical volumes info is saved in the lvm metadata, and the tools from lvm2 can be used to scan them out and setup the kernel DM by ioctl. I am curious that who does this work during booting so we can mount lv as rootfs, systemd?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer by myself.
http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/lvm-guide-en/Booting-linux-from-LVM-volumes/

Quote the content from above link.

> Here are the important steps involved in booting from LVM:
>
> 1.The BIOS executes the boot loader which is very often Grub
>
> 2.The boot loader has its own code for reading partitions and filesystems. So it knows how to read files from the /boot partition
>   which contains the linux kernel image (vmlinuz-x.y.z) and the
>   initramfs (initrd-x.y.z.gz). It first loads these two files into
>   memory. Then it executes the kernel image and it tells the kernel
>   where the initramfs is located in memory. The boot command line is
>   also passed to the kernel. This command line contains the important
>   parameters for the kernel such as root=/dev/volgroup/lvroot.
>
> 3.The linux kernel starts and executes its initialization code. Then it reads the initramfs from the memory. The contents is uncompressed
>   into a new location in the memory.
>
> 4.The contents of the initramfs is now available. The program/script called init is now executed. This script which is specific to each
>   linux distribution is responsible for finding the root filesystem.
>
> 5.If the LVM Physical Volumes are stored on the top of a RAID disk, the init program will first execute dmraid/mdadm to make this raid
>   disk available.
>
> 6.Then the init script will run programs such as pvscan/vgscan/lvscan to detect the LVM volumes located on the disks The LVM volumes are not
>   usable yet. They have to be activated first. This is done by vgchange
>   --available y or vgchange -ay.
>
> 7.The init script reads the virtual file called /proc/cmdline to see what is the name of the root filesystem specified on the boot command
>   line.
>
> 8.The root filesystem is mounted in a temporary directory such as /rootfs and other things such as /rootfs/proc and /rootfs/dev may also
>   be mounted.
>
> 9.The initscript executes a chroot to /rootfs. This means that this directory becomes the new root for the processes which will be
>   executed. When a process reads /bin/something it will read
>   /rootfs/bin/something in reality.
>
> 10.The secondary init program, the one which is stored on the root filesystem is now executed and it finishes the initialization with an
>   access to the real root filesystem.